# Auto on/off 12v DC timer for garden irrigation

Tags: irrigation, timer

I have 7 raised garden beds with irrigation setup. Irrigation consists of a 100w solar panel going into a 120w max Controller. This charges 2 12v DC batteries connected in parallel. The batteries are used to power a 400gph water transfer pump which pulls water from my rain collection system when manually connected.

I have been trying to find a DC timer (as AC is not available and an inverter would kill the batteries) that will automatically turn on the pump at a set time then turn it off after a set time frame has passed with at least 2 on/off per day.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a timer that I can use for this purpose? It will be located outside but can be installed in a element tight enclosure if needed.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Imagine there should be one or a few.  I know there are timers for watering lawns, but don't know how they work, AC or DC or sun dial.  Would also place this question on https://gardening.stackexchange.com/.  They might know of something

Comment: You can use any 7 Day timer for this ( as long as the Amp Rating is matched) - but your transfer pump should not really be consuming more than 2 amps.  -- just do a google search. Depends if you want digital or Analog.

Comment: Croo post of https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/62801/20139

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick: Search for: "12v 7 day timer" there is a large variety of them available to you. You can get them mail order, via the web or from your favorite box store. I will not recommend a brand but they range from about $10.00 to over $100.00 US.